# How can I programmatically force a search in the UISearchBar?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

How can I force the UISearchBar to automatically start a new search (like pressing the Search button)? Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: No duplicate as we do not want to show the keyboard, we want to start the search process like it's done when you click on the search button. The problem is that the logic is in a library where we don't have access to(no source code)

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. You should put that information in the question then. ;)

Comment: similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993379/how-to-programmatically-tap-a-point-on-the-ios-keyboard)

Comment: is this part of some automation test? or is this a behavior you actually want on your app?

Comment: Have the some problem too.

Answer (score 24):

I found that I needed to set the UISearchViewController to active before changing the value of the search field programatically to make UISearchViewController automatically perform the search:

```
// Need to set the searchDisplayController to active to 
// make the changes in search text trigger a search.
self.searchDisplayController.active = YES;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = @"New search string";
```

**Swift 4**

```
self.searchController.isActive = true
self.searchController.searchBar.text = "New search string"
```

Comment: This works beautifully, and fixed a host of other problems I was having, such as certain delegate methods not being triggered.  Thank you.

Comment: Worth to notice, that order matters :)

Comment: How we can do this with searchbar that created from storyboard?

Answer (score 6):

Just have the search input field become the first responder:

```
[self.searchInputField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what is self in this context?

Comment: As I figured out how we can access the text field of the search bar this becomeFirstResponder is only displaying the keyboard but we do want to start a search automatically

Comment: Oh, I usually create my own handle to searchInputField, as @tiguero says from the search bar or just by initializing it myself. If you don't have access to the input field then it's going to be more complicated.

Comment: We did find some kind of workaround. We just start the search using the library twice and cancel the first search before it returns anything and we have everything as we like. It's kind of bad but it works as expected -.-

Answer (score 4):

You can force your searchBar,

**Objective C:**

```
[self searchBar:yourSearchBarName textDidChange: yourSearchingString];
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
self.searchBar(self.yourSearchBarName, textDidChange: yourSearchingString)
```

This will trigger your searchBar.

Answer (score 3):

After making sure that the text you want is inside your search bar you can call `self.searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar)` (passing in your search bar) assuming you have already implemented this UISearchBarDelegate method `searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)`

Comment: For me, this is the best option, also because it is very readable

Answer (score 2):

```
let searchBar: UISearchBar = /* The Searchbar */
searchBar.delegate?.searchBar?(searchBar, textDidChange: "")
searchBar.text = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you only need to make an implicit call to the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:` on your `UISearchbarDelegate`. Have a look to the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UISearchBarDelegate) for more info about this delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we do have the problem that the searchBar is in embedded in a view where we don't have access to and therefore this approach is not working. Do you have any other hint?

Comment: But somewhere in your code you should have a delegate class to handle the search - aren't you?

Comment: We don't have access to that part of the code as it's implemented in a library that we use where we don't have access to the sourcecode. We're trying to find the delegate that's used there but we're not successful so far.

Comment: Who will handle the search - you or your library?

Comment: THe Library and that's the problem

Comment: @tiguero how do you mean 'make an implicit call'.. `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` only works *after* the search button was clicked. so it's useless here isn't it?

Comment: @abbood the purpose of the delegate method is to be called when the search button was cliked: i agree on that but that shouldn't prevent you from invoking your delegate method yourself: [self searchBarSearchButtonClicked:mySearchBar]. That's what i meant.

Comment: @tiguero i'd be interested to know if the apple store accepts that kind of code

Answer (score 0):

seems dumb, but works, so it's not dumb ;)

```
NSString * forceReload = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text = forceReload;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

If you just have a UISearchBar (not a UISearchViewController):

```
let searchBar: UISearchBar
searchBar.text = "foo" // Reset the search text
searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() // Select the field and bring up the keyboard
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked - Swift 4

```
   searchBar.text="Amber"
   self.searchBar(self.searchBar, textDidChange: "Amber")
```