# how to programmatically tap a point on the iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, kif-framework

I'm using [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF) to automate my app, and I'm trying to automate typing something into a `UISearchBar` and searching for it. Unfortunately I couldn't find a [satisfactory way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447573/how-can-i-programmatically-force-a-search-in-the-uisearchbar/12447701#comment28058115_12447701) to do that by programmatically clicking on the search button after I've entered my search text.

So instead, I considered simply using KIF's [tapScreenAtPoint](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/blob/master/Classes/KIFUITestActor.m?source=c) method. The problem with that method is that it does the following:

```
CGPoint windowPoint = [window convertPoint:screenPoint fromView:nil];
view = [window hitTest:windowPoint withEvent:nil];
```

It's expecting the tap to actually touch a view.. and since the keyboard is obviously not a view this test won't be able to trigger the search button on the keyboard.

How can one programmatically tap a button on the keyboard? I think this would be very useful for any automation-test suite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to tap the "Search" button in the keyboard.  The accessibility labels on return keys don't follow any sort of sane pattern.  Looking in the accessibility inspector, you'll see "SEARCH" but that may not be consistent on all OS versions.

**Update**

You can trigger the search button by adding `\n` to your `enterText...`

```
[tester enterTextIntoCurrentFirstResponder:@"query\n"];
```

[image: Search button in selector]

Comment: very interesting.. however your code above doesn't work (although I'd argue that it should).. could `not enabled` above have something to do with it?

Comment: I assume as soon as text is entered the text field loses the Not Enabled trait and shouldn't be an issue.  You could try adding `\n` as the last character in your `enterText:...` to see if that triggers it.

Comment: excellent! the `\n` trick worked! can you please update your answer and take out the `@"SEARCH"` thingie b/c it doesn't work (we don't wanna mislead the folks do we?)

Comment: and one a side note.. is there a definite way to wait for a search result to appear on the table? right now I just make it wait for some random time like so: 
    ` [self enterTextIntoCurrentFirstResponder:@"tripoli\n"];
[self waitForTimeInterval:4.2];
    
    [self tapRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] inTableViewWithAccessibilityIdentifier:kMapTableIdentifier];`.. is there a more precise way?

Comment: b/c the above way of doing it is very brittle.. sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.. depending on the internet speed

Comment: my bad.. last question was dumb.. i simply assigned an accessibility label to the search result cell and waited for it.. and.. DONE!

Comment: i updated your answer for you.. hope you don't mind (and of course.. feel free of updating the update! :p

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to use:

`[tester clearTextFromAndThenEnterText:@"sample test" intoViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"SearchField"];`

`[tester waitForViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"search"];`

`[tester tapViewWithAccessibilityLabel:@"search"];`

Accessibility label for the return key is "search" in this case, you can verify it by using accessibility inspector app.

But be careful, the 'return key' (search/done/return/whatever) won't be pressed if you are adding a text that ends with cap letters, for example:

"sample TEST"

The 'shift' button will be pressed and the 'return' button won't, even if you try to use the "tapScreenAtPoint" method.

It happened to me and got me crazy for a long time until I figured out what was actually going on.

Comment: This is a much better answer than the programmatic newline.